# Программа про массивы непонятна

Tags: любой-язык

Я не могу понять программу, помогите!

> В массиве целых положительных и отрицательных чисел А[4,4], получученном случайным образом, вычислить сумму элементов побочной диагонали и третьего столбца. Если сумма элементов побочной диагонали больше суммы элементов третьего столбца, то выбрать из массива все числа меньше 25, и  записать их в одномерный массив, который затем рассортировать в порядке возрастания. В противном  случае подсчитать количество четных чисел в массиве А и записать его на место третьего элемента первой стоки.

Comment: Что именно непонятно?

До слов "Если сумма элементов побоч..." понятно? 

Если нет, то исходя из слов "побочной диагонали больше суммы элементов третьего столбца" видимо надо считать 2 суммы (одна диагонали, а другая столбца).

Теперь понятно?

Comment: @mikillskegg, а зачем закрывать учебные задания ? Я никого не призываю их решать. 

А вот подвинуть мысли ученика в нужном направлении - что в этом плохого ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм. По порядку:

**Побочная диагональ** - диагональ с юго-запада на северо-восток. Т.е., с левого нижнего угла до верхнего правого. Посчитали сумму элементов. Допустим, она равна **X**.

Третий столбец он и в Африке третий столбец. Сумма равна **Y**.

**X > Y**: Проходим весь массив и записываем все числа, которые меньше 25 в одномерный массив. Сортируем массив так, чтобы вначале числа были маленькие, а в конце - большие.

**X <= Y**: Проходим весь массив, считаем количество чётных чисел - допустим **Z**. Записываем значение **Z** в ваш массив **A**, а конкретно в первую строку, третий столбец.

Comment: Бывают, конечно, дурацкие задания с непонятными условиями. Но в этом надо всего лишь рассмотреть всё по порядку. Кроме "побочной диагонали" :)